# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe while opening chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have following environment at my local
Chrome 67
Python 3.5.0
Selenium 3.12.0

I have downloaded chromedriver with version 2.39

I have .py file as follows

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="hromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
time.sleep(5)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('Python')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

I am getting following error.

```
C:\Python354\python.exe D:/formf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PCPNDT/form.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "C:\Python354\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python354\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe
```

I also tried with other webdriver like geckodriver.exe still same error.

Please help me out to resolve this error.

Thanks!

Comment: if you are in linux you need to put the downloaded chrome driver in usr/local/bin and try again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At a first glance to your code trial it seems there is a minor bug in the *value* of the *argument* **executable_path**. Instead of `hromedriver.exe` it should have been:

```
# Windows OS
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
# Linux OS
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

---

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe
```

...implies that the the program/script was unable to initiate/spawn the **`ChromeDriverService`** through **chromedriver.exe**.

The potential reason for the error can be:

- Due to missing the entry **`127.0.0.1 localhost`** in **`/etc/hosts`**

### Solution

- *Windows OS* - Add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `/etc/hosts`
- *Mac OSX* - Ensure the following entries:

  ```
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1 localhost
  fe80::1%lo0 localhost
  ```

### References

As per the discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service geckodriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2903):

- Selenium does not require `127.0.0.1 localhost` to be explicitly set in the host file.
- However it is mandatory requirement to map *localhost* to the ***IPv4 local loopback (127.0.0.1)***
- The mechanism of this mapping does not have to be through the hosts file always.
- On *Windows OS* systems it is not mapped in the hosts file at all (resolving localhost is done by the DNS resolver).

### TL;DR

[How to reset the Hosts file back to the default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default)

Comment: Awesome !! it worked. my chrome exe I renamed it to "hromedriver.exe" just to avoid the name conflicts coz I had added several versions. I have no entries in the /etc/hosts file I made now its absolutely working fine. Thanks

Comment: local host change worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake into the executable address :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="hromedriver.exe")
```

It should be :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
```