# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /mnt/sdb1/firefox/firefox unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0. Why?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
geckdriver --version 0.33.0
firefox 119.0
python2.7 using selenium 3.141
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/mnt/sdb1/firefox/firefox')
driver.get("file:///mnt/sdb1/root/foo.html")

assert "Python" in driver.title
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Python<title/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    some text
    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run **python foo.py**, the new Firefox TAB opens up and *geckodriver.log* is created but contains nothing. The `driver.get("file:///mnt/sdb1/root/foo.html")` HTML page does not load within the new Firefox TAB that was created.

### Why does Firefox unexpectedly exit?

```
(closing Firefox completely and running the selenium-script causes firefox to start up from scratch and there is a pause before the script exits with 

*selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /mnt/sdb1/firefox/firefox* )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue from this question:
[selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe while opening chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727595/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s)

Anyway, to avoid confusion with localhost path to the driver you can import Service from selenium:
Example in python (don't forget to use the new capabilities method):

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.FireFox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```