# getting the error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am new to selenium so i tried open google.com webpage with python and i get this error.

```
raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /Users/Roseline/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/mac-x64/121.0.6167.85/chromedriver
```

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

#keep chrome browser open after program finishes
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

i expected a pop up telling me it can't be granted permission then i will have to go to my system preferences and authenticate and grant it permission. But there was no pop up, only this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe while opening chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727595/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

It can't use the chromebrowser in your system. Try this, it works on my side.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: i tried installing ChromeDriverManager but it gives an error ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from chromedrivermanager) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

Comment: also, it shows the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
even if there is no red squikly line under it